# Auto load files without MANAGE

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to load files within the same.

Comment: What does this have to do with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can require access to directory instead of a single file:

https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory

With some restrictions:

> On Android 11 (API level 30) and higher, you cannot use the
> ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action to request access to the
> following directories:
>
> - The root directory of the internal storage volume.
> - The root directory
>   of each SD card volume that the device manufacturer considers to be
>   reliable, regardless of whether the card is emulated or removable. A
>   reliable volume is one that an app can successfully access most of the
>   time.
> - The Download directory.
>
> Furthermore, on Android 11 (API level
> 30) and higher, you cannot use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent
> action to request that the user select individual files from the
> following directories:
>
> - The Android/data/ directory and all subdirectories.
> - The Android/obb/
>   directory and all subdirectories.

Source: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-tree-access-restrictions

Comment: 1) No, user cannot select root as you can see here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#document-tree-access-restrictions

Comment: 2) Yes, you can persist as you can see here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions

Comment: 3) Yes, you can edit the files via outputStream as you can see here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#edit